# How to enable SPUrl in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: spurl

I'm upgrading from SharePoint 2007 to 2010 and the `$SPUrl:~sitecollection` expression doesn't appear to be working anymore. It replaces `~sitecollection` with the current site URL instead of the root URL. For example, if I'm in `http://mysite.com/its/itsinternal`, and I have a reference to `<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/its %>`, the URL is formatted as `http://mysite.com/its/itsinternal/its`. Is there a configuration somewhere that controls this?

Comment: Could it be that "its" is a managed path and "itsinternal" actually is a site collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with Microsoft and being unable to get it running the way I want, I've opted to use absolute URLs when I'm trying to reach the top level site collection from a nested site collection.

Answer (score 0):

`<%$SPUrl:~SiteCollection/ ...%>` seems to be working fine for me in 2010